# Inserting data in a dockerized mongodb on startup

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to get a local docker setup running with a mongodb instance for a node API that I'm working on. I'm using the docker image found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo).

My `Dockerfile` looks as follows:

```
FROM mongo
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME root
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD pw
ENV MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE foo
ADD scripts/init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

What I would like to achieve, is on startup of my docker container, I would like to insert some dummy data to the mongodb, something like:

```js
db.collection('bar').insertOne({foo: 'foo'});
db.collection('bar').insertOne({foo: 'bar'});
db.collection('bar').insertOne({foo: 'baz'});
```

In the official documentation, it mentions that

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
> with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
> specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
> test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

Im running into several problems with this. Running `db.collection('bar)` will tell me that `db.collection is not a function`.

I've already looked at and tried many different solutions on stackoverflow (switching to docker-compose, using different scripts, creating new users?, etc etc), but I still don't have anything running locally.

How can I simply insert some dummy data in the mongo db on startup? I'd very much prefer to stick with a simple `Dockerfile`, and not switch to anything different. I would just like to get my init script to run, and insert the data with a couple of `db.collection('bar').insertOne({})`.

Additionally, in the Docker dashboard (on mac), when I click on my container, and click on the "CLI" button, and type the following:

```sh
⚡ docker exec -it 8430a5d39fbfd5e77a034bb563e3ebcaabbd6736c62121740420a190804fcef /bin/sh; exit
# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("58a59bd0-2fe5-4345-95a3-b78c70f65707") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.1
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    https://docs.mongodb.com/
Questions? Try the MongoDB Developer Community Forums
    https://community.mongodb.com
> show dbs
> show collections
Warning: unable to run listCollections, attempting to approximate collection names by parsing connectionStatus
> db.auth("root", "pw")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
>
```

I cant seem to authenticate, even though I'm setting the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in my `Dockerfile`, I would like to understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [latest mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/index.html), I cannot find any reference to `db.collection(collectionName)`.

However, I do find references to `db.createCollection(collectionName)` and `db.getCollection(collectionName)`.

By modifying your script to use those functions instead, I can get the docker instance to start correctly. This is probably due to the fact that you use the `FROM mongo:latest` image.

You can find the complete pull request [here](https://github.com/thepassle/custom-elements-api/pull/10) but in short, your Dockerfile is correct and the script should only use functions that are visible in the documentation.

The way to run a script on first startup in mongodb in indeed to use the `COPY scripts/init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` command.

What I am guessing happens is that the node library you are used to and the `db` capabilities that the docker image use are different.

As for connecting to the database, if you want to avoid the admin login you should use the `mongodb://user:password@mongourl:port/dbname` format.

In this specific case, something like `mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/customelements`